# Using log4net with ASP.Net WebForms in Visual Basic

Tags: logging, web-config, log4net

I am failing to get log4net to log anything in ASP.Net webforms. This is what Im doing:

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="MyLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\inetpub\MySite\Logs\MyLog.log"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="10KB"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="MyLogger">
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="MyLogFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
</log4net>
...
```

**Global.asax**

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="log4net" %>

<script runat="server">
    Public Shared Logger As ILog

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(New FileInfo("Web.config"))
    End Sub
```

**Test.aspx**

```
Protected Sub cmdTest_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdTest.Click
    Dim logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger")
    logger.Debug("A test debug message")
End Sub
```

I've given 'Everyone' access to the 'C:\inetpub\MySite\Logs' folder and STILL no logs appearing. Any ideas what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like these you can use internal debugging to see what log4net is doing or where it is failing (cf. this question: [How does one troubleshoot log4net when it stops logging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677640/106567)).

I did not test it but I think your problem goes a way if you call the `Configure` method (without arguments) instead of the `ConfigureAndWatch` method. You do not need to watch the web.config file for changes because any change to this file will reset your application pool.

If you want to use an external configuration file (and `ConfigureAndWatch`) then you have to make sure that the file can be found. E.g. like this:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(New FileInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"),"Web.config")))
```