# ERROR: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's

Tags: c#

I have developed a console app that has the following:

- MyProject

  - Program.cs
  - log4net.config
  - AssemblyInfo.cs
  - MyProject.csproj
  - MyProject.sln

In Program.cs:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
namespace MyProject
{
    class MyClass
    {      
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        ....
    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="./log/logger.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And when I run my program like dotnet bin/Debug/net8.0/log4.dll

I get a message:

> log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the
> application's .config file. Check your .config file for the 
> and  elements. The configuration section should look
> like:

Although the program is running, and the log is being written.

But I tried creating a .config file and I get the same message. Any idea how to solve this please? (I'm still pretty new in C#)

Comment: You should put the configuration in your app.config file. Or appsettings.json if you're using .net core

Comment: Is this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166126/log4net-separate-config-file-not-working

Comment: I don't have an app.config. None is being created when I selected .NET New Project - Console App in vscode